# Нужно растянуть 3D анимацию на весь экран сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, 3d

Всех приветствую!
Перепробовал много разных вариантов, в частности которые обычно применяются к видео. Растягивает по краям лево-право, а высоту приходится задавать в пикселях. И наоборот.

Знаю, с виду вопрос выглядит банальным, но это не так))

В div вставке указываю width="100%" и это срабатывает, 
а вот если ставлю в height 100%" то он не видит, и выставляет стандартный-минимальный размер. 
В css тоже наколдовывал по-разному)
Был ли у кого опыт такой вставки анимации? Какие методы могут помочь чтоб анимация была прижата ко всем четырем частям экрана?

```html
  <div class="sketchfab-embed-wrapper">
    <iframe title="A 3D model" width="640" height="480" src="https://sketchfab.com/models/f86f444dc7cc4458a0140f05a03c5896/embed?autostart=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; vr" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: @O K Анимация или видео?

Comment: анимацию, с сайта: https://sketchfab.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:(Добавив параметры iframe)
Проверил у себя - работает:

```
<style>
    iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<div class="sketchfab-embed-wrapper">
    <iframe title="A 3D model" width="640" height="480" src="https://sketchfab.com/models/f86f444dc7cc4458a0140f05a03c5896/embed?autostart=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; vr" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странное поведение, опять применяется к width: 100%. А к height не применился. Документ чистый с нуля, без доп стилей. Чекнул в других браузерах, тоже так. Я напишу сюда если пойму что не так.

Comment: @O K Это странно. У меня и в chrome и в safari на весь экран и по ширине и по высоте.

Comment: @O K Попробуйте полностью скопировать мой код и добавить в новый файл.

Comment: Вот я думаю что проблема в чем-то другом. Не в вашем коде.

Comment: Я так и сделал.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
    iframe {
    position: absolute; 
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0; 
    } 
</style>

<div class="sketchfab-embed-wrapper">
    <iframe title="A 3D model" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://sketchfab.com/models/f86f444dc7cc4458a0140f05a03c5896/embed?autostart=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; vr" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Если в диве ставлю width="100%" height="100%" и в стиле выставляю

```
iframe {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```